# socket.io connect to multiple processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

I am trying to set up a chat server using `socket.io` and `socket.io-redis` so I can have the process on multiple processors/servers.

I am having issues integrating `socket.io-redis` into the already working system that runs on one server with one process. When I cluster the process on to two processors using: `pm2 start chat.js -i max`. Socket.io can no longer keep the connection.

To solve this issue, I read that I need to use redis, so I installed redis and it is running, and according to `socket.io-redis` docs all I need to do is this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

So, I have taken that to make this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3032);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.broadcast.on('Message', function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        socket.to(data.room).emit('Message', data.message);
    });
});
```

And when I run on a browser I can not connect, I am getting this:

```
{
    "code":1,
    "message":"Session ID unknown"
}
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald no I did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    socket.join('public_room');

    socket.on('join', function(data){
        io.to('public_room').emit('test',{a:10});
    });     
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer for better understanding.